# How to update calculated values in subclasses

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

As the title suggests I am looking to update calculated values in a subclass. I have the FPBViewModel's `Parameters` collection as a DataGrid's ItemSource in my WPF page. The `HeatingAirflow` is just the sum of the `MinAirflow` and the `FanAirflow`. What is the best way to make the `HeatingAirflow` parameter's value automatically update when either the `MinAirflow` or `FanAirflow` parameter's value is changed in the DataGrid?

I have looked into using a calculator method, but the implementation feels clunky as I end up creating a new `ParameterViewModel` and replacing the "old" vm in the `Parameters` collection. Also for reference there are many calculated values in the FPBModel class, this is just the easiest example. Ideally there would be way to use the PropertyChanged event, but for some reason I haven't been able to get there in the nested classes.

FPBModel

```
public class EngineFPB : EngineMechanicalEquipment
{
    private Parameter _minAirflow;
    private Parameter _fanAirflow;
    private Parameter _heatingAirflow;

    public Parameter MinAirflow
    {
        get { return _minAirflow; }
        set { _minAirflow = value; }
    }

    public eParameter FanAirflow
    {
        get { return _fanAirflow; }
        set { _fanAirflow = value; }
    }

    public Parameter HeatingAirflow
    {
        get => _heatingAirflow;
        //set => _heatingAirflow = _minAirflow + _fanAirflow;
    }

    public FPB(Element element)
    {
        UTILUnitConverter UC = new UTILUnitConverter();
        double min = element.min;
        double fan = element.fan;

        _minAirflow = new EngineParameter("Min Airflow", min, false);
        _fanAirflow = new EngineParameter("Fan Airflow", fan, false);

        _heatingAirflow = new EngineParameter("Heating Airflow", 0, false);
        CalculateFields();
    }

    public void CalculateFields()
    { 
        double heatingAirflow = Convert.ToDouble(_minAirflow.Value) + Convert.ToDouble(_fanAirflow.Value);
        _heatingAirflow.Value = heatingAirflow;
    }
}
```

FPBViewModel

```
public class FPBViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel> _parameters = new ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel> Parameters
    {
        get => _parameters;
        set
        {
            _parameters = value;
            RaiseProperty(nameof(Parameters));
        }
    }

    private ParameterViewModel _minAirflow;
    public ParameterViewModel MinAirflow
    {
        get => _minAirflow;
        set
        {
            _minAirflow = value;
            RaiseProperty(nameof(MinAirflow));
        }
    }

    private ParameterViewModel _fanAirflow;
    public ParameterViewModel FanAirflow
    {
        get => _fanAirflow;
        set
        {
            _fanAirflow = value;
            RaiseProperty(nameof(FanAirflow));
        }
    }

    private ParameterViewModel _heatingAirflow;
    public ParameterViewModel HeatingAirflow
    {
        get => _heatingAirflow;
        set
        {
            _heatingAirflow = value;
            RaiseProperty(nameof(HeatingAirflow));
        }
    }

    public FPBViewModel(EngineFPB fpb)
    {
        _minAirflow = new ParameterViewModel(fpb.MinAirflow, false);
        _fanAirflow = new ParameterViewModel(fpb.FanAirflow, false);
        _heatingAirflow = new ParameterViewModel(fpb.HeatingAirflow, true);

        _parameters.Add(MinAirflow);
        _parameters.Add(FanAirflow);
        _parameters.Add(HeatingAirflow);
    }
}
```

Parameter Class

```
public class EngineParameter
{
    private string _name;
    private object _value;
    private bool _isReadOnly;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }
    public object Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => _value = value;
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get => _isReadOnly;
        set => _isReadOnly = value;
    }

    public EngineParameter(string name, object value, bool isReadOnly) 
    {
        _name = name;
        _value = value;
        _isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

ParameterViewModel

```
public class ParameterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Parameter _parameter;
    private bool _isReadOnly;

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get => _isReadOnly;
        set => _isReadOnly = value;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _parameter.Name;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get => _parameter.Value;
        set
        {
            if (!_isReadOnly)
            {
                _parameter.Value = value;
                RaiseProperty(nameof(Value));
            }
        }
    }

    public ParameterViewModel(Parameter parameter, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
        _isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using a Command in the ViewModel? That is the first thing that comes to my mind. if you cant utilitize commands, a converter could maybe work. When I have something where the UI causes a cascading change to a Model, i try to keep the mechanism in the VM or View. I agree that adding a Calculator would feel clunky. But a one-off Command or Converter is usually more friendly.

Comment: Handle `PropertyChanged` on the contributing properties, and update `HeatingAirflow.Value` (or just replace `HeatingAirflow`) when either of their values changes. Also update `HeatingAirflow` when either of the other parameter viewmodels is replaced, of course, and take care to unhandle events (or use weak references) so you don't confuse the garbage collector. That's the canonical way of doing this. A command or a value converter would be a very strange way of going about it. Value converters have no business in a viewmodel, and commands exist to be executed by views.

Comment: The parent viewmodel should be in charge of all of that. I've found that it's a very good rule for relationships between child viewmodels to be the sole responsibility of the parent viewmodel. Just have the children raise events so the parent can act when it needs to.