# How to communicate between child control and parent window with big hierarchy in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is big hierarchy of controls: window , inside window there is control, inside one more... 
All of them have view models. Before creating parent window , i generate some Field and pass as parameter of the window.
I need to display the field on child control, how i can pass this field from parent's window view model to child control's  view model not using the chain of properties/events/delegate commands  and using mvvm ? 
What about ways to communicate between parent window and child control if there are many layers between?

Comment: Every child viewmodel is a property of its parent, or resides in a collection that is a property of its parent. Every parent is responsible for its own children. Sometimes, a parent may concern itself with its children's children ([here's such a case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363562/how-to-update-calculated-values-in-subclasses) -- the pattern there is that the child viewmodel exists in order to own a value, so semantically, a new child viewmodel is much like a change in the child viewmodel's value property).

Comment: In a view, you can bind to a property of a property of a property of the view's viewmodel: `<Label Content="{Binding SelectedDepartment.SelectedTeam.Leader.FullName}" />`, for a somewhat contrived example. Your question is a bit abstract, so it's hard to give a helpful answer. It would be better if you could provide specific examples of things you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of layers in between should be irrelevant if you follow the MVVM pattern. If for example all can happen in a single view model then there should be no issue. If however you have a separate view models as context for the window and a specific control, then it would be a good idea that the relationship gets reflected on the view model side, having the top view model *contain* the bottom one for example.

Comment: you mean parent view model contains child ? In xaml to do something like that:
 <parts:CommonInfoChild  DataContext={Binding Path=CommonInfoChild ViewModel } />
??

Comment: well I mean that the parent view model has a reference to the child one, either a reference or, the child being part of a list. The xaml is the view side, I don't think that's what you are after.

Comment: what about the way to set created in parent view model child view model as a DataContext of child control?

Comment: You can expose the child view model as a property to the parent one, then use data binding.